# Не запускается MOM java

Tags: java, glassfish

Показывает ошибку настроить переменную среды, но она у меня и так настроена и указан путь к jdk. Не понимаю, в чем ошибка

[image: переменная среды]

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Возможно, вам надо создать переменную именно с таким именем, которое указано в сообщении об ошибке. Я мог бы вам его тут скопировать из сообщения об ошибке, но вы его картинкой поместили, а не текстом, потому скопировать его не могу.

Comment: Переменная среды для среды исполнения Java должна быть JAVA_HOME со знаком подчеркивания посередине. У вас JAVAHOME. Когда запускаете брокер очередей imqbrokerd.exe, то он, возможно и не смотрит эту переменную окружения. В любом случае у вашего брокера есть своя переменная среды IMQ_JAVAHOME, где можно указать местоположения папки JRE (или JDK). Либо же при запуске просто написать `imqbrokerd.exe -javahome путь_к_папке_JRE`